# AlertDialog with single choice list - I need some items nonclickable

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have AlertDialog with single choice list.
I want to put some 'fake' items inside - like labels of following items. I'm using different layout for regular item and for 'label' item. It it OK.
My problem is: How to make labels NON clickable?

Here is my getView code:

```
// @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
if (m_data.get(position).BaseElementType == ElementType.Divider)
{
    convertView = m_li.inflate(this.m_groupResurceID, null);
    TextView post = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    post.setText(m_data.get(position).TypeToString());
    post.getClickable();
}
else
{
    convertView = m_li.inflate(this.m_itemResurceID, null);

    TextView post = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    post.setText(m_data.get(position).Header);

    ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    Drawable dr = m_data.get(position).TypeToIconId();
    dr.setColorFilter(BGMapsApp.IconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    img.setImageDrawable(dr);
}
```

Comment: How does your getview() method look?

Comment: This code isn't efficient, but I'm using it for 10-15 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple!
Just put this to adapter code:

```
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        //return super.isEnabled(position);
        return (m_data.get(position).BaseElementType != ElementType.Divider);
    }
```

Now some items become non clickable :)